# How many $4$-digit lock combinations are possible if each digit in the code may appear at most twice?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, permutations

**Question**
A lock combination code is made up of $4$ numbers ($0-9$). Each number can occur at most twice, e.g. $4764$ would be allowed but not $4464$ as the number $4$ has occurred more than $2$ times.Therefore, how many possible combination codes are there?

I know that there are $10,000$ possible combinations **if** repetitions are allowed. However I'm unsure as to how to answer the question. Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: What does "Each number can occur two times mostly." mean?  Do you mean a number can occur $0,1$ or $2$ times?

Comment: @lulu For example '4764' would be allowed but not '4464' as the number '4' has occurred more than 2 times.

Comment: Got it.  I think, then, you meant to say "Each number can occur at most two times."

Comment: As a hint:  break it into three cases.  Case I:  no number repeats.  Case 2:  exactly one number repeats.  Case 3:  two numbers repeat (as in $3443$).

Comment: The complement method may be quicker than finding it straight up: find the number of ways you have $3$ digits the same and $4$ digits the same and subtract from $10000$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a possible solution using the Principle of Inclusion/Exclusion:

$\textbf{Case 1}$ (digit is repeated $3$ times):

Choose the repeated digit in $10 \choose 1$ ways.

Choose the remaining digit in $9 \choose 1$ ways.

Order the digits in $\frac{4!}{3!} = 4$ ways.

$\textbf{Case 2}$ (digit is repeated $4$ times):

Choose the repeated digit in $10 \choose 1$ ways.

Order the digits in $\frac{4!}{4!} = 1$ way.

So the number of combinations that don't satisfy your constraint is $(10 * 9 * 4) + (10 * 1) = 370$. Subtracting these from the $10,000$ total combinations yields $\textbf{9,630}$ ways.

Answer (score 1):

Solution without using the Principle of Inclusion/Exclusion:

Add by number of pairs of numbers: $0$ pairs $+$ $1$ pair $+$ $2$ pairs

$=$ (pick $4$ of the $10$ order matters) $+$ 
(pick which will be repeated and where and the other $2$ numbers order matters) $+$ 
(pick number for each pair and location of first and second pair)

$=P(10,4) + 10*{{4}\choose{2}}*P(9,2) + {{10}\choose{2}}*{{4}\choose{2}}*1$

$=5040$ $+$ $4320$ $+$ $290$

$= 9630$